# How to tell if computer is on and operating on a network

Tags: windows, icmp

I have a computer that's configured for magic WOL packets, so the adapter will respond to ICMP. Pinging the computer doesn't seem like it'd provide a lot of useful information since it'll always respond even while off. The machine runs Windows 7 and was wondering if there any small and fast protocols available I could use to retrieve information about the status of the computer. Preferably something small and can be implemented quickly in the form of sockets through php/python. The least amount of information I want is whether the computer is off or on.

I'm thinking about using MS-HGRP to list all supported systems since I know for a fact the machine appears in the home network. But I wan't see if there's something much more efficient than that.

Comment: Normally, having Wake on LAN configured doesn't cause the adapter to respond to ping requests.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, computer was off and it pinged back. Perhaps this is NIC vendor specific?

Comment: Could be.  I've never heard of a NIC that offloads ICMP, though!  Check the TTL in the reply; if you're lucky it will be different when the machine is on (and hence, presumably, replying to pings via the operating system) than when it is off (when the adapter is apparently replying to pings all on its own).

Comment: But isn't actually seeing the computer off enough evidence?

Comment: why the down? If it's because of pinging, I'm not lying.

Comment: my idea was you might be able to use the TTL from the ping reply to determine whether or not the machine was on.  But if echo suits your purposes that's probably more reliable.

Comment: Can you tell us the adapter model, just for future reference?

Comment: Sorry harry, I was just pinging externally without knowing it, you were right. The ECHO service is also useful in that since it's a service that isn't installed by default on a windows machine, I'll be able to distinguish one system on the network externally without another computer responding to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time was, systems implemented an `echo` service on TCP port `7`. If it is still easily available on your machine, it could be as easy as `echo foo | nc address echo` and seeing if there is a response. It'd be a simple enough service to re-implement, if it isn't easily available.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, anything UDPish?

Comment: echo is available in Windows, but has to be installed - the feature is named "Simple TCPIP services" in Windows 7.  Remember you'll need to reconfigure the firewall as well.

Comment: Harry, since your comment isn't an answer I'll just upvote it and give sarnold the up. Since it eventually led me to the answer anyways. Hope that's okay.

Comment: @chaz: note that the comment notification features requires a `@username` in the comment. (And only one works.)

Comment: @Harry: Note chaz's comment -- if you give that as an answer, you'll get an upvote from me, too. :)